# What is a Scriptive syntax for running stages in parallel

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

So I want to run following jobs in parallel -

```
ccsmp_tag_Android()

ccsmp_tag_OpenVms-ia64()

ccsmp_tag_epoll-linux26-x64()

ccsmp_tag_iphoneOS_176()

ccsmp_tag_linux26-i386()

ccsmp_tag_linux26-x64()

ccsmp_tag_multios()

ccsmp_tag_win_platform()
```

I am trying to write a scripted syntax for this. Please help me with this any suggestions are highly appreciated

Comment: You can check out some of the following [Examples](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/#parallel-from-list), combined with the [build](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/) step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of a scripted pipeline stage running parallel jobs:

```
stage('Parallel Jobs') {
  parallel(
    'Job 1': {
      ccsmp_tag_Android()
    },
    'Job 2': {
      ccsmp_tag_epoll-linux26-x64()
    },
    ... (and so on)
  )
}
```

Depending on your jobs definition, you may also have to put a "node" around:

```
stage('Parallel Jobs') {
  parallel(
    'Job 1': {
      node {
        ccsmp_tag_Android()
      }
    },
    'Job 2': {
      node {
        ccsmp_tag_epoll-linux26-x64()
      }
    },
    ... (and so on)
  )
}
```

See: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#scripted-pipeline

Comment: Thank you soooooooooooooo much

Comment: You‘re welcome. If an answer works for you, you can also mark it as accepted.